# Excluding directories with grep

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I just tried:

```
michael@Pascal:~/noisynet$ sudo grep -rio --exclude-dir={/ece,/home/michael/pytorch,/sys,/proc} 'hello' /
```

The very first match is:

```
/home/michael/pytorch/.git/logs/HEAD:hello
```

Why is it looking in `/home/michael/pytorch`?

Comment: Which directory are you starting in? Maybe try removing the `/` in front of the directory names.

Comment: I'm in /home/michael/noisynet directory

Comment: Removing the `/` in front of the directory names should resolve your issue.

Comment: if I remove / it would look for these directories in /home/michael/noisynet, which is not what I want.

Comment: You are starting from your root directory `/`, so what you say makes no sense. The `/` at the end of your grep command indicates this!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you're saying. If I'm in /home/michael/noisynet and I want to exclude '/sys' directory, how would specifying --exclude_dir=sys be correct?

Comment: michael@Pascal:~/noisynet$ ls /
bin  boot  daily_lock  data  dev  ece  etc  home  initrd.img  initrd.img.old  lib  lib64  lost+found  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  shared  srv  storage  sys  tmp  usr  var                                                                       vmlinuz  vmlinuz.old

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**This will work well**

```
grep -rio --exclude-dir={ece,pytorch,sys,proc} 'hello' /
```

Note: This will also exclude other directories with same name.

**Explanation:**

Man page of grep gives below snippet

> ```
>    --exclude-dir=GLOB
>           Skip  any command-line directory with a name suffix that matches the pattern GLOB.  When
>           searching recursively, skip any subdirectory whose base name matches GLOB.   Ignore  any
>           redundant trailing slashes in GLOB.
> ```

This means given pattern `(GLOB)` will be applied only to the actual name of the directory, and since a directory name don't contain / in its name, a pattern like /proc will never match.

Hence, we need to use `--exclude-dir=proc or --exclude-dir=sys (or --exclude-dir={proc,sys})` just names for directories to be excluded without '/'.

Comment: Works, even though it's mind boggling why would anyone implemented such an awkward way to search directories.